# Use Sitecore / GlassView RenderImage with an item (MVC)

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I have a bunch of items in View that aren't fields on the model and just items.  I really want to user RenderImage so I don't have to re-invent all the html code, but it really wants an item or and item of the GlassView type.

Is there a simple way to just force feed an item into GlassView.RenderImage?

How about sitecore's Render Image?  It just wants a field value, but I want to give it an item?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a new model which extends the existing (Sitecore template based) one.

For example you have the `IArticle` model, which has every field of the item, but not much else, as usual. You should create a new model, which inherits from the original, and you can add new fields, which will be mapped by Glass, if set properly. You can use the following [attributes](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/tree/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/Configuration/Attributes) for example:

- `[SitecoreNode]` (define an item by id or path)
- `[SitecoreParent]` (by hierarchy)
- `[SitecoreQuery]` (sitecore query)
- `[SitecoreChildren]` (hierarchy)

**Models**

```cs
/// This model is based on the Sitecore template
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "something")]
public interface IArticle : IBaseItem {
    [SitecoreField]
    string Title { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField]
    string Content { get; set; }
}

/// This model defines additional items.
public interface IArticleDetail : IArticle {
    [SitecoreNode(Id = Constants.MainBannerId)]
    IBanner PromoBanner { get; set; }

    [SitecoreQuery("somequery")]
    IEnumerable<ITag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you `GlassView` inherits from the `IArticleDetail`, and the model binder propagates the additional fields as well.

If you want to render (editable images), you can just use the following syntax:

```cs
@RenderImage(Model.PromoBanner, m => BannerImage, isEditable: true)
```

or

```cs
@Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model.PromoBanner, m => BannerImage, isEditable: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`@RenderImage` will only accept a type of `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image` but if you have a property on your view of `Item`, I would suggest just using the standard HTML helper field render:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Field Name", Model.SomeSubItem)
```

Comment: It's not a field though.  It's a media item.  I'm just using my own html, but figured there is a better way.